# Upload a changed file via BitBucket web interface

Tags: git, file-upload, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I'm looking for a way to upload a replacement file to a BitBucket repository without having to clone it first. In my current situation the repository is far too large to clone locally (due to bandwidth restrictions) so I'm not able to do the usual clone/commit/push. The file I wish to replace is a binary file.

The BitBucket web interface provides a means to *download* a single source file from a git repository using the "Raw" link when viewing the file concerned. It also provides a way to create a new file in an existing directory using the "New File" link, however this is only useful for text files that can be copy/pasted into the edit field. I cannot see a way to upload a new file.

It's also possible to edit a file via the web interface without having to clone the repository locally, however this also only works for text files.

Do you know if there's a web API to upload a replacement version of a file? Or alternatively a way to upload a new binary file and then I can delete/rename as needed to simulate a change.

Comment: How about doing a shallow clone you can just clone the latest commit of one branch. Shouldn't be that bandwith expensive then.

Comment: I thought about that, but is it possible to push from a shallow clone? Research seems to suggest one can't without some complex "grafting" which I'll look into. Also, the "shallow" checkout is still very large - I really only need to change one small part of the entire project.

Comment: Yes, it is. Except if you use an ancient version. Since 1.9.0 Git supports data transfer from and to a shallow clone.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it - thanks. A shallow clone is still too large for my case, but it is smaller than a full clone and therefore worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket added this to their api, you can post the file to the [bitbucket src api endpoint](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/src#post).

Comment: If this exists in the API, is there a corresponding possibility in the web interface too? Or an app that can do this? Always assembling a curl commandline for this task seems a bit tedious.